# String selection filtering by 2 parameters in SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Can not figure out how correctly filter inside my joined tables.
When I use:

`String selection = " quiz_list_id " + " = ? " + " AND " + " LevelID " + " = ? ";`

Nothing happens when i hit button which has correctly assigned name from database. 
Where should I look to add missing parameters?

```
 public ArrayList<Question> getNLevelQuestions( int TestLevelID, int quizListID) {
    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();


    String table = QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " JOIN " + QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME +
            " ON " + QuizListTable._ID + " = " + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID;


    String selection = "quiz_list_id" + " = ? " + " AND " + "LevelID" + " = ?";

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(quizListID), String.valueOf(TestLevelID)};

    Cursor c = db.query(table,
            null,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question question = new Question();
            question.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("question_id")));
            question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question")));
            question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("option1")));
            question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("option2")));
            question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("option3")));
            question.setOption4(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("option4")));
            question.setAnswerNB(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("answer_nb")));
            question.setQuizListID(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("quiz_list_id")));
            questionList.add(question);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
    return questionList;
}
```

Here my StartingScreenActivity that pass information to main activity

```
PracticeList = findViewById(R.id.Practice_n_group);
    for(int i=0; i<categorySize;i++){

        practiceButton = new Button(this);
        practiceButton.setText("" + categoryName.get(i));
        practiceButton.setId(i+1);
        final int index = i;
        practiceButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        practiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startQuiz(v.getId(), categoryName.get(index).toString());
            }
        });
        // adding button to layout
        PracticeList.addView(practiceButton);
    }
}

private void startQuiz(int practiceListID, String quizListName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartingScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PRACTICE_ID, practiceListID);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PRACTICE_NAME, quizListName);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ);
}
```

Comment: How do you call `getNLevelQuestions`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below (update your query as well selection args string):

```
String table = "SELECT * FROM " + QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME + " a INNER JOIN " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " b ON " + QuizListTable._ID + " = " + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID;

String[] columns = new String[]{
            "question_id",
            "question",
            "option1",
            "option2",
            "option3",
            "option4",
            "quiz_list_id",
            "answer_nb",
            "_id",
            "name",
            "LevelID"

    };
String selection = " b.LevelID=? " + " AND " + " a.quiz_list_id=?";

String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ String.valueOf(JLPTID), String.valueOf(quizListID)};

    Cursor c = db.query(
            table,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the method [query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for an sql statement, but only to query a table. 
You must use the [rawQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method.
So set the full sql statement like:

```
String sql ="SELECT .... WHERE LevelID  = ? and quiz_list_id = ?";
```

and then:

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ String.valueOf(JLPTID), String.valueOf(quizListID)};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
```

*Note*: in your sql statement use proper qualifiers for the columns, so there is no ambiguous column names.

Comment: Post the sql statement as it is now.

Comment: I made the update to that topic. Or should I post it here?

Comment: Post here the sql statement that you pass as 1st parameter to rawQuery().

Comment: Apologise for my late reply. made suggested modification and posted sql statement which I query inside getAllJLPTLevels method. Now I get ambitious column name _id. However in my String[] columns all columns have different name.

Comment: Are you sure that error is caused inside getAllJLPTLevels()? Post the error log.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made a lot of changes to generalise my question and posted solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone thank you for the suggestions. Eventually the problem was that I did not pass one of the parameter from my query to the startQuiz method. Instead I was passing id of the selected button.

Changes:

from

```
 startQuiz(v.getId(), categoryName.get(index).toString());
```

to

```
 startQuiz(TestLevel, categoryName.get(index).getId(), categoryName.get(index).toString());
```

and in the method below added another one required parameter:

```
private void startQuiz(int testLevel, int practiceListID, String quizListName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartingScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LEVEL_ID, testLevel);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PRACTICE_ID, practiceListID);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PRACTICE_NAME, quizListName);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ);
}
```